# Apache: How to configure different SSL certificates for different subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2

For testing purposes, I would like to create 5 different subdomains, each with a different SSL certificate. Can someone point me to the right direction to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at this:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Essentially, under a different `<VirtualHost>` block, you have a different `ServerName` denoting what the subdomain/domain is, and then different `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` for each different SSL certificate.